# How do I automate saving of .csv files to delimited .txt files using C#?

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I have about 23 .csv files. I opened them all in Excel and then manually saved them as tab delimited .txt from within Excel. How do I automate this process instead?

Simply put, I want to convert .csv files into tab delimited .txt files using a C# winform, where I can push a button and have all of the .csv files in my C:\csv\ folder automatically converted into tab delimited .txt files.

I am hesitant about simply renaming .csv files into .txt files by changing the extension because it seems that something gets changed in the process. To be precise, my program runs into errors reading a text file whose extension was renamed and changed to .txt from .csv, but does not run into errors when reading a text file that has been converted from .csv to delimited .txt by Excel. I think it's because I saved them as tab-delimited text within Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution assumes your files are all relatively small and will not cause `OutOfMemoryExceptions` if the entire file is loaded into memory at once.

```
  DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\path\to\root");
  FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();

  foreach (string path in files.Where(x => x.Extension == "csv").Select(x => x.FullName))
  {
      string input = File.ReadAllText(path);
      File.WriteAllText(input.Replace(',', '\t')
  }
```

Also, a couple notes about your final paragraph; There is no difference between a .csv and .txt file. They are both flat text files. csv just stands for "Comma Separated Value" I can have a text file that is technically a "csv" and I can have a .csv file who's contents aren't actually in the format. Changing the extension won't magically make the commas rewrite themselves as tabs but there is no reason that wouldn't work if your code could read the original csv format.

EDIT: Couple more things; Firstly, I updated the example code so it uses a directory path as it's starting point and gets all files from there. Secondly, just wanted to not, if your files are too large for this solution use StreamReader/StreamWriter inside the same foreach loop. msdn has an adequate example so I won't post anything here, you just have to read the file line by line, replace the comma's with tabs, write the line to the output file.

Using a csv reader to do a more robust transformation;

```
 using System.IO;
 using LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv;

 List<string> output = new List<string>();

// open the file "data.csv" which is a CSV file with headers
using (CsvReader csv =
       new CsvReader(new StreamReader("data.csv"), true))
{
    int fieldCount = csv.FieldCount;

    string[] headers = csv.GetFieldHeaders();
    while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
    {
        output.Add(String.Join("\t", csv.NotSureWhatThisPropertyNameShouldBe));
    }
}
```

The `CsvReader` class gives you an indexer for the values in each line but I'm not exactly sure what property you would use to get the entire line a string array for example which is the intent above.

Comment: um, this looks helpful, why would someone downvote it to -1?  evan, i forgot to mention that the folder may contain a variety of different file types.  how do i ensure that only the files ending in .csv or .xls or .xlsx get converted into .txt?

Comment: @phan that's a different problem on it's own but use the `DirectoyInfo` class to get `FileInfo` instances for all the files in your target directory and then you can use a simple LINQ query to filter down to just .csv, .xls, and .xlsx files. Also, what you're doing for csv files won't necessarily work for those Excel formats. I'm not knowledgeable on them, but I'm pretty sure there is plenty of meta data included in the file that will make it substantially different from the csv equivalent.

Comment: With regard to the downvoter I can't say because they didn't care to comment. There are a few valid concerns they could have but most likely they're just an idiot because that answer gives you the basic idea. Yes, it isn't enterprise software ready. No, I will never provide an answer with that robust of code on SO.

Comment: @phan one question; can values in the file have commas in them? For example could I have something like `val1,"value2, is a sentence, with commas!",val3` because that would obviously make it so that code does not work and if that is the case the problem is more complicated and I would recommend using a csv parser.

Comment: off the top of my head, i'm not sure but it is possible.  i understand you're replacing commas with tab and trying to mimic what Excel does when saving data as delimited text.  i'm wondering if there's another way to just automate excel's method of saving data as delimited text

Comment: @phan you certainly could automate Excel actions, again I think it's a lot more work and would be a strange way of doing it. If that is the case I would just recommend using this library to read the file. I'll give a very brief sample of how to use it; http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use Interop:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.IO;
using System;

public class ExcelInterop : IDisposable
{
    private Application _excelApplication;

    public ExcelInterop()
    {
        _excelApplication = new Application();
    }

    public void ConvertDirectoryOfCsvFilesToTxt(string inputFolder, string outputFolder)
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(seasonPath).Where(f => !f.EndsWith(".csv")).ToList();

        foreach(string file in files)
        {
            string outFilePath = Path.Combine(outputFolder, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) + ".txt";
            ConvertCsvToTxt(file, outFilePath));
        }
    }

    private void ConvertCsvToTxt(string inputFilePath, string outputFilePath)
    {
        Workbook workbook = _excelApp.Workbooks.Open(inputFilePath, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        workbook.SaveAs(outputFilePath, XlFileFormat.xlCurrentPlatformText, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false);
        workbook.Close();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _excelApplication.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_excelApplication);
    }
}
```

Based in part from [DotNetPerls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel) and [VbCity](http://vbcity.com/forums/t/162577.aspx) plus my own recollections with Interop. This was written in a text file and may not compile or work correctly, but should get you started.

You would call it with something like

```
using(ExcelInterop excelInterop = new ExcelInterop())
{
    excelInterop.ConvertDirectoryOfCsvFilesToTxt("C:\\csv", "C:\\txt");
}
```